# poll() system call core dump with segmentation fault in Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am facing segmentation fault in `poll()` system call and dumps core for below code

```
wait_time(int wait_time)
 {
   struct pollfd fds;

   poll(&fds, 0, wait_time);

 }
```

From Other functions

```
void xyz()
{
    int a=0;
    if (a==2) {
          wait_time(3);
          a=0;
     }
     a++;
     //something else i am doing
 }

main()
{
      while(1)
      {
          xyz();
      } 

}
```

How can I solve core dump on poll() system call?

Comment: If you're just want to use the function as a sleep-function, then why don't you simply pass `NULL` as the first argument? Besides, there are other ways to pause the process for a specified amount of time, that are more geared toward sleeping, like e.g. [`nanosleep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html).

Comment: Have you tried passing `NULL` instead of `&fds` ?

Comment: Alternatively, you could set `fds.fd` to a negative value for the function call to ignore it.

Comment: After fixing the trivial errors and warnings in the above code, adding #include, etc, it runs perfectly fine on my Linux box. Both as a 32 and 64-bit executable. Which seems to indicate that the problem is in "something else I am doing", or some such.

Comment: We need enough code to replicate the problem. The bug is most likely in code not shown.

Comment: so why aren't you guys voting to close?

Comment: I have modified the code poll(&fds, 0, wait_time);

to poll(NULL, 0, wait_time); Compilation done. Need to execute the same in my setup. I will share test report after the fix.  Thanks a great help.

Comment: Thanks to all poll(NULL,0,wait_time) works. I ran it for 2 days there were no core dump on poll(). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below solution works fine,

```
wait_time(int wait_time)
{
    poll(NULL, 0, wait_time);
}
```